# Tkinter Scrollbar porblems when using update() inside a for loop

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I'm creating an entry list which works fine when I don't use the update() but when I use it the scroll bar is grayed out.

This is the code that works fine:

```
from tkinter import *


root = Tk()


main_frame = Frame(root)
main_frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
canvas = Canvas(main_frame, highlightthickness=0)
canvas.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=1)
scrollbar = Scrollbar(main_frame, orient=VERTICAL, command=canvas.yview)
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
canvas.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: canvas.configure(scrollregion = canvas.bbox("all")))
second_frame = Frame(canvas)
canvas.create_window((0,0), window=second_frame, anchor="nw")

for i in range(100):
    x = Frame(second_frame)
    x.pack(fill=BOTH, padx=20, pady=0)

    resultados_entry = Entry(x, width=73)
    resultados_entry.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=1, padx=0)
    resultados_entry.insert(0, str(i))

root.mainloop()
```

And this is the one that doesn´t:

```
from tkinter import *


root = Tk()


main_frame = Frame(root)
main_frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
canvas = Canvas(main_frame, highlightthickness=0)
canvas.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=1)
scrollbar = Scrollbar(main_frame, orient=VERTICAL, command=canvas.yview)
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
canvas.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: canvas.configure(scrollregion = canvas.bbox("all")))
second_frame = Frame(canvas)
canvas.create_window((0,0), window=second_frame, anchor="nw")

for i in range(100):
    x = Frame(second_frame)
    x.pack(fill=BOTH, padx=20, pady=0)

    resultados_entry = Entry(x, width=73)
    resultados_entry.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=1, padx=0)
    resultados_entry.insert(0, str(i))

    root.update()

root.mainloop()
```

I want to use root.update() inside of my for loop because I want to display the entries as they are created. I don't want to wait until the for loop finished to start displaying them.

Comment: It is a common mistake that `<Configure>` is bound on `canvas`.  It should be bound on `second_frame` instead because it is `second_frame` being get resized when widgets are added to it, not `canavs`.

Comment: @qwerty000. Your second code , u can't put root.update() inside for looping condition block. The qwerty000 should be outside of looping.

Comment: Very harmful. https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Update+considered+harmful